# Pods copying headers from x86_64 and arm64 folders in frameworks and causes multiple commands produce error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, lipo

I am trying to add a custom framework to my iOS app. The framework includes code for both x86_64 architecture and arm64 architecture.
When I try to build my project on my MacOS for simulator I receive multiple errors of the same form:

[image]

As I see the problem is that its trying to copy files from both folders, the ios_x86_64_simulator and ios_arm64 and thus produces same headers which causes it to fail.

I have tried doing clean install of my whole Pods, changing the order of **build phases**, excluding architectures "arm64" for debug and release builds both for my project as well as all targets however I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I fixed the issue with combining frameworks for both architectures using lipo.

For example:

```
lipo -create ios-arm64/A.framework/A ios-x86_64-simulator/B.framework/B -output combined.framework
```